# React components with shared state that are far away

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React so please excuse me if this is a noob question but I really could not find the answer in the DOCs or elsewhere.

Let's say I have two buttons with a counter that share the state but are far away from each other in terms of the placement in the UI.

[image]
[image]

The [documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) the common owner component for both buttons should own the state. It makes sense if the components are next to each other like in the example but what if my buttons are each part of a different UI group and are far away in terms of nesting? My state holder would be the root of the document and I would have to pass a handler function down through many layers. And what if I need to add new component somewhere else that also needs to know the state? Would I have to modify all the parent components in the way to pass the state down? That is tremendously impractical.

Without React I would have some global Subscribe/Publish pattern like [jQuery Observer](https://gist.github.com/dharFr/1928176) and all UI elements could subscribe/publish to it regardless of their nesting position.

How does React solve this?

---

Related question: If I need to load/save the state to DB, how do I pass a reference of the controller (or Whatever) to each React component that stores the state?

Comment: What you are looking for is something like Redux, it holds all the app state in one object, then, your containers (not longer just components), will have access to a part of the app state wherever they are invoked.

Comment: I had exactly the same thought when I first started looking at React. It seems that child components can not be responsible for mutating shared state, only the parent owner can do that, and as you say must pass the mutator function all the way down the hierarchy. And if that state is held at root, then the entire state object gets replaced and presumably that causes re-renders throughout the whole app, just because of one little change of state! Your scenario is surely extremely common, I can't see how you could use React without Redux.

Answer (score 4):

**1** for global state you may use **[REDUX](http://redux.js.org/)**

**Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps**

for connect/subscribe component with that state ,you should use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)

**If components are far away in terms of nesting,** you may connect/subscribe them to redux store, and take only neccessary part of state. They will update if only neccessary part is changed.

[article](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-redux/) that explains how you can do your case

**to learn how to use redux** you can watch this videos from creator of redux ([Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov))

1.[getting-started-with-redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

2.[building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)

3.I definitely recommend to you **[discordapp rectiflux](https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/103538784460615680)** channel. because you allways can ask any question online.(there you can find contributors of that tools)

---

**2** **alternative way that less verbose then redux is** **[MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)**

MobX is a battle tested library that makes state management simple and scalable by transparently applying functional reactive programming (TFRP). The philosophy behind MobX is very simple:

Anything that can be derived from the application state, should be derived. Automatically.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, your answer is helpfull for me so +1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to look at the [Flux stores](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html). In short, stores are like model in your application. You can listen to change (subscribe) and also modify their properties (publish). You can see how it was done in [example app](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/TodoStore.js).

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to go with [Redux](http://redux.js.org).

Redux is enabling use cases like yours in a way simpler fashion :)
It will help you with all the state and make your life much easier.

Some good resources for learning:

- [The Redux Website](http://redux.js.org)
- [Video courses from Dan Abramov, the creator](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) [Free]
- [Awesome course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/) [Not free]
- [Building Applications with React and Redux in ES6](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-redux-react-router-es6/table-of-contents)
- And finally take a look at [this youtube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w-oQ-i1XB8) [Free]

Answer (score 1):

Managing state in the middle layers of your app should be avoided where possible. This data belongs in a store, which holds the global state of the app. Then each component accesses the state via its props.

The naïve approach to get the data down to the component is to pass the store through all the layers of your app "manually", i.e. through props.

Smarter alternatives exist, which use *connected* components, that access the global state through the *context* (as opposed to the props). Typically, the presentational component (your button component) is wrapped in a container component that handles this connection to the store, then passes the data in via props.

There are numerous frameworks that facilitate this process, links to which are already provided in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to share simple states, try this ( I am the author): [react-provide-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-provide-state)

Otherwise I will recommend Redux. It has become the most popular tool for managing application states.

In the applications being working on, we use Redux to manage the main application states and almost all other states. But we use 'react-provide-state' for simple, UI only states like Modal, Checkbox states.